# Auto height iframe javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un problema, estoy creando por medio de `JavaScript` un `iframe`

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = 'web.html';
  iframe.scrolling = 'no';
  iframe.style.width = options.width;
  iframe.style.border = 'none';
  iframe.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  iframe.id = 'ol-widget';
  element.appendChild(iframe);
```

Quiero obtener el `Height` de `web.html` y ponerlo en el `iframe`

Comment: necesariamente debe ser en javascript puro? o puedes utilizar JQuery?

Comment: Solo javascript puro

Answer (score 1):

Como la altura del `iframe` no existe sino hasta que se ha cargado el contenido (html y css) primero debes dejar que cargue el contenido y luego actualizar el tamaño del iframe.

Para esto puedes poner un escuchador al evento "load" para que ejecuté una función:

```
iframe.addEventListener('load', actualizar_altura);
```

Luego definimos la función `actualizar_altura()` de la siguiente manera:

```
function actualizar_altura() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('ol-widget');
    iframe.style.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight+'px';
}
```

Eso sería todo, coméntame si te sirvió, espero que soluciones tu problema.

Comment: Hola, viendo la consola me tira este error,
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://domain.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: @Jadel Esta solución únicamente funciona cuando el archivo web.html se encuentra en el mismo servidor (porque sino se aplicaría la capa de protección de CORS - Cross-origin resource sharing). por lo tanto al usar esta linea de código: iframe.src = 'web.html'; vas a necesitar que web.html se encuentre en el mismo servidor que esta corriendo tu programa.

Comment: y como le hace facebook, para sus plugins ?

Comment: @Jadel hay que habilitar CORS para que se puedan hacer peticiones entre diferentes páginas (dominios) y tiene que estar habilitado en ambos lados, si la página que estas cargando en el iframe no es de tu propiedad, puede que ellos deshabiliten CORS y no puedas acceder a "document" por javascript (por seguridad). Te dejo un enlace que te guiará para habilitar CORS en diferentes servidores y lenguajes (esta en ingles, pero en español no hay uno tan completo): https://enable-cors.org/server.html